# SQL script of joining multiple tables shows duplicated record

Tags: sql

> The McLean family is challenging their total condo fees. Retrieve all invoice data related to condo fees (including details) for the McLean family for invoice 20065.  Selecting appropriate data to calculate the total condo fees for invoice number **20065**.
>
> Tips: guest# is **'G5'.**
>
> startdate is **'2019-08-03'**
>
> And they stayed in the condo for a week.

I write a script. But always shows duplicated output (two duplicated records). How can I do this without using the keyword "distinct"?

The expected output only shows one row of record.

```
select i.inv#, i.condo#, i.guest#, g.rlname, cs.startdate, cs.enddate, c.WeeklyFee
    from guests g join reservations r
        on g.guest# = r.guest#
            join invoicedetails id 
                on r.rid = id.rid
                    join invoice i  
                        on id.inv# = i.inv#
                            join condostays cs
                                on i.guest# = cs.guest# and i.condo# = cs.condo#
                                    join condos c
                                        on cs.condo# = c.condo#
                                            where i.guest# = 'g5'
                                                and i.inv# in (20065)
                                                    and startdate = '2019-08-03';
```

My output of showing duplicated records

[image]

Schema:

[image]

ERD:

[image]

Expected output (only one row of record output):

[image]

Comment: Should be simple to debug. Change Select to "SELECT *", comment out all your joins, then add each join one by one until your result goes from 1 row to rows. Then look at the table and figure out why that specific join is causing duplicates. There's some data scenario you probably aren't accounting for